# Expected number of questions

Tags: probability

I have this question that I am unable to answer

> One of the numbers 1 through 10 is randomly chosen. You are to try to
>   guess the number chosen by asking questions with "yes-no" answers.
>   Compute the expected number of questions you will need to ask in each
>   of the two cases:
>
> Your ith question is to be "Is it i?", i = 1, 2, ...., 10.

My formulation would be

$ E[X] \\ = 1*P(1 \ question) + 2*P(2 \ questions) + 3 * P(3 \ questions) + \ ... +  10*P(10 \ questions)\\ = 1 * 0.1 + 2*0.2 + 3*0.3 \ + \ ... 10*1
$

The answer however, is 5.5 and im not sure why that is.

Comment: P(1 questions) = P(2 questions) = ... = P(10 questions) = 0.1

Comment: @MikeEarnest I think that would quality as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

$P(1$ questions $) = P(2$ questions $) = \dots = P(10$ questions $) = 0.1$.

Comment: Because we are asking for the probability of getting the answer in exactly 2 questions, for example, not the probability of getting it within 2 questions.

Comment: but why would the number from the first question counted as possible to ask about?

Comment: the probabilities are nonetheless $0.1$. I think asking "Is it 1?", then "Is it 2?" etc. is the way to handle the question (up to random permutation). So it boils down to the probability to pick each and every number (and i suppose it is uniform)